# mongoose-paginate does not render virtual fields of the mongoose model

Tags: arrays, mongoose

mongoose-paginate does not render virtual fields of the mongoose model. Any solution for this ?

https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate

Answer (score 1):

If you use the virtual config at the `schema level` then probably this settings would render the virtuals for you

```js
const options = {
    // lean: true - exclude this string if you have
    sort: '-updatedAt',
    // etc.
}
```

or if you are like me who adds the virtual config at the document level, for example:

```js
// jobModel is my job schema and questions is a virtual collection mapped from questions schema
const doc = await this.jobModel.findOne({ _id: id }).populate({ path: 'questions' });

// This returns me the parent doc and the virtual data
return doc ? doc.toObject({ virtuals: true }) : null;
```

then you might need to keep the `lean: true` for virtual fields to populate like so:

```js
const options = {
    lean: true,
    sort: '-updatedAt',
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose-paginate can render virtuals, but only if you exclude lean() operation.

```
 const options = {
        // lean: true - exclude this string if you have
        sort: '-updatedAt',
        // etc.
  }
```